# Where should I ask about Computer Science Applications?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I'm looking for existing applications of Graph Summmarization on social networks. Is it on-topic?

Comment: I would think that [datascience.SE] would be the better venue, but I'm not familiar with their scope.